# Matching field with multiple values

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to get all documents that match the words: Apples, Oranges, and Pineapples in the field Fruit. So basically I want something like this:

```
{
  "query":{
    "bool":{
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "fruits": ["Apples","Oranges","Pineapples"]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How do I accomplish this with a simple trick like that?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use "terms" in place of "match" to get the documents

```
{
   "query": {
      "terms": {
         "fruits": [
            "apples",
            "oranges",
            "pineapples"
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Note: You should lowercase the values because "terms" query find exact matching and if no analyser is used default analyser (Standard Analyzer) is used by elasticsearch while indexing text values which lowercased the values before indexing it

Comment: The `Note` here is such a bummer. I literally wasted half a day trying to find out why it didn't work in my case until I found this answer. Thanks!

Comment: Briliant that's simply what I needed. Thanks for the tip about necessity to lowercase terms